# iOS Swift App SceneKit with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, scenekit

I'm currently developing an app on iOS using mostly UIKit, it's an informations and health app, not a game. It's for a company that produces chairs, so we planned to add 3D models of each chair in a small view.

I managed to import the 3D-models as chair.dae and display them using a SCNView. The complete app is build with Storyboard and Segues, combined with a UINavigationController, so the user could get back and forth on the NavigationBar.

Now the problem is, the Navigationbar on every other ViewController is working as intended.
Only on the ViewController that has the SCNView added, there is no NavigationBar at all. I used a normal ViewController, added a SCNView and connected it to my navigation with a Show Detail Segue.

Another issue is, while most Views get pulled from the right side of the screen when i switch, this one is pulled from the bottom and replaces everything

Is there a way to force it to show a navigation bar?
I tried with following, but didn't change anything

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like correct behavior for a Show Detail. Per Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html):

> This segue displays the new content using the showDetailViewController:sender: method of the target view controller. This segue is ***relevant only for view controllers embedded inside a UISplitViewController object***. With this segue, a split view controller replaces its second child view controller (the detail controller) with the new content. Most other view controllers present the new content modally.

(emphasis added).

Why not a Show instead?

Comment: The actual UITableViewController containing the navigation menu is inside a ContainerView and with the Show segue, there is only a small view, like the size of the ContainerView for every connected ViewController.
Using the Show Detail i had the normal size again.

Comment: I switched it to Show for testing purposes, it stayed the same way, then i deleted the Segue completely, adding a new Show segue and it worked then.
Only problem now, i have only a tiny ViewController in my Interface Editor

Comment: Could be an autolayout bug unrelated to SceneKit. Swap in a solid color UIView and post screenshots.

Comment: As it is only in the interface editor, i switched the size from inferred to master, inferred uses the size of the underlying container view i think, even when the Segues replace the parent view controller